# which one is better for storing data in viewstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, custom-controls, viewstate

I create a new asp.net custom control. This control get its data via a list of string.
Now I want to know what is the better solution for me? storing `List<String>` or `string[]` ?

Comment: I think you should use IEnumerable<string>, so that your clients are not restricted to any.

Comment: Clients? He's talking about storing it in the viewstate!

Comment: just got it wrong i thought he is talking about making some property of so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533276/215380), you'd be better off storing it as an array, as the list itself adds some storage overhead.

Whether or not you create a list out of the array *after* you retrieve it from the viewstate is up to you.

To those saying "use a list, it gives you more niceties than an array" - once the collection is in the ViewState, it doesn't matter whether it has nice `Add` methods or not.

```
public List<string> MyItemsFromViewState
{
    get { return new List<string>((string[])ViewState["MyItems"]); }
    set { ViewState["MyItems"] = value.ToArray(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The general practice is use `string[]` when you are working with static arrays, basically when you don't need to add /remove elements (only access via index).

If the collection needs to be modified, use `List<string>`.

So in your case, use `List<string>` :)

Answer (score 1):

It makes little difference as far as `ViewState` is concerned. The size of both should be almost the same. I would prefer `List<string>` for the extra niceties provided by `List<T>`

Answer (score 0):

list of string would be better for you to put on the viewsate and get from view state because list of string will provide you with more flexibility in work